# How to wrap text around a widget in Flutter like the layout of a book?

Tags: flutter, layout

I want to wrap some long text around a widget, such as a container which will display an image positioned in the top right or left of the screen.

So, the 'empty' space around this widget will be surrounded by text, like the layout of a book.

I cannot figure this out as using a Row or Column doesn't work as that is only going to layout text in one direction.

[image: example image]

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  height: 150.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. '
                  'Nullam auctor fermentum erat, eu lacinia sem eleifend nec. '
                  'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et '
                  'malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi a turpis turpis. '
                  'Praesent eget metus a est posuere laoreet nec sit amet dolor. '
                  'Phasellus ultrices ipsum eget odio lacinia, eu sollicitudin est '
                  'pharetra. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus '
                  'et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris eget diam id velit '
                  'tincidunt elementum. Sed ultrices enim et pellentesque luctus.'
                  'Ut posuere pulvinar ligula, non suscipit magna ultrices vitae.'
                  'Quisque lacinia odio eu egestas pulvinar. Pellentesque nec '
                  'ornare justo. Donec sed pharetra dui. Nulla pulvinar nisi '
                  'quis risus lobortis, non fermentum tellus dignissim.',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```